# TWTweetComposeViewController doesn't allow edit

Tags: iphone, ios

When I present the TWTweetComposeViewController I am able to scroll the message in the window, but I am unable to edit the text.

Here is the code I am using to present the TWTweetComposeViewController :

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *twitter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [twitter addURL:article.articleURL];
    [twitter setInitialText:message];
    [viewController presentModalViewController:twitter animated:YES];
```

I tried this in an empty project, and it allowed me to edit the tweet just fine. **Is there an option that I need to set to allow the tweet to be editable?**

---

***Edit for clarification:***

- I think I've narrowed it down to something in my project not allowing
  any UITextViews becoming first responders
- I made an empty UIViewController in my app delegate, and presented
  the twitter controller there and was still unable to edit the text
- I also tried just adding a UITextView onto that blank controller and
  the same thing happened
- UITextFields work just fine though

Comment: Where are you calling this code from?

Comment: Are you at the 140 character limit already once you present it?

Comment: Hi, I am currently not at the 140 character limit. I am presenting it from a UIViewController that is the frontViewController of the ZUUIRevealController.

Comment: I should also note that the the TWTweetComposeViewController does not ever become first responder.

Comment: I think I've narrowed it down to something in my project not allowing any UITextViews becoming first responders, I made an empty UIViewController in my app delegate, and presented the twitter controller there and was still unable to edit the text. I also tried just adding a UITextView onto that blank controller and the same thing happened.

UITextFields work just fine though.

Comment: Any UITextView categories in your project?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I forgot I had that implemented.

Comment: @Allen Would be helpful to know what code is in the categories maybe that will provide a clue as to the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear, I had actually overwritten the canBecomeFirstResponder for all UITextViews - therefore disabling it on all UITextViews. I got rid of it and now it works fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) you cannot change the tweet after the user has viewed the tweet.